# Пустое значение ID_FS_UUID

Tags: linux, lvm, udev, device-mapper

Необходимо написать правило для udev демона для выполнения определённых действий при обнаружении устройства.

Правило:

```
KERNEL=="sd*",SUBSYSTEM=="block",ACTION=="add",ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="?",RUN+="/opt/bin/create_virtual.sh %k"
```

Вместо значения переменной окружения ID_FS_UUID подставляется соответствующее значение блочного устройства.

Однако на одной из систем параметр ID_FS_UUID оказался пустым.

Система МСВС 5.0. Параметры оставил по-умолчанию. При этом разделы создаются "замапленными" с помощью device-mapper модуля (на системе автоматически устанавливается lvm).

Вывод `cat /proc/partitions` :

```
major minor #blocks  name
  8     0   33554432 sda
  8     1     104391 sda1
  8     2   33447330 sda2
253     0   29327360 dm-0
253     1    4096000 dm-1
```

Вывод `parted -l /dev/sda`:

```
Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system   Flags
 1      32,3kB  107MB  107MB   основной ext3          boot
 2      107MB   34,4GB 34,3GB  основной               lvm
```

Вижу, что у раздела sda2 не указана файловая система, но не могу понять, почему. А мне именно этот раздел и нужен.

Подскажите, как мне определить параметр ID_FS_UUID для этого раздела.

Comment: Потому что у вас там LVM том, поверх которого уже идут разделы и на них уже файловые системы.

Comment: @0andriy То есть /dev/sda2 - физический том, не имеющий файловой системы?

Comment: Я честно говоря с lvm на практике ни разу не сталкивался, поэтому так же, как и вам, мне необходимо будет читать документацию. Но пока такой задачи не возникло.

Comment: @0andriy понял. Всё равно спасибо.